How to properly "skip" a heading level when it is implicitly conveyed by page layout
Sometimes, semantics is contained within design. My question is how to translate this semantics into HTML when some levels of the heading hierarchy are skipped because they are implicit.
For example, a page can have sections with almost all of them containing H2 titles, and it is clear that they are on the same hierarchical level. But some of them have no H2, instead, directly columns or cards containing H3 headings. I wouldn't put these headings as H2, because it is incorrect as regards the implicit structure, but I cannot skip H2 either because this would tie this section's content to the previous one with a H2.
Another example is a fixed column, aside in an article with various sub-sections: table of contents, call-to-action, author information, publication date. Some of them, like the call-to-action, have a title, but others, like the author information, don't. I don't want screen readers to consider the second as a part of the first if it is following it. Visually, a dividing line makes it clear, but they don't see it.
What I think would be right to do, in this kind of situations, is to put an invisible title which would still be read by screen readers, like so. But it is only what I guess and I have never read that as an advice.

If you start a section straight without any heading, you take the risk that a screen reader user navigating by heading might miss the part before the first heading of the section.
Screen reader users can also navigate by landmarks and sections are included in landmarks, but according to several WebAim surveys, navigation by landmark/section is less frequent than navigation by heading.
Note that, for navigation by section/landmark to work well, if there are several landmarks with the same type (as it is usually the case for sections), they should ideally have an aria-label/aria-labelledby.
So it could be quite important to put an heading at the beginning of every section, so to make sure that nothing can be missed, regardless of the mode of navigation used.
If the heading is too obvious, visually implicit as you say, you can hide it from the screen by using .sr_only/.visually-hidden.
In any case, rules are clear: you should never skip a level, and you especially triple shouldn't do it just because of visual design.
